# Can I add range of ports in netsh add urlacl?

Tags: windows, acl, administration

I use the following command to allow listening of specific HTTP ports:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:[port]/ user=DOMAIN\UserName
```

But if I need to open a range of ports, can I setup a single rule?

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this?  Been researching it for a while and can't find a decent solution.  Answer below is useless if you have a large range of ports.

Comment: did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Having a range would go against the reason for having the urlacl system in the first place: to force apps to bind to the most minimal portion of the namespace possible, without interfering with other apps.

Answer (score 12):

I didn't find any way to specify a range so I went with using built-in FOR command:

```
for /L %i in ([port_start],1,[port_end]) do netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:%i/ user=DOMAIN\UserName
```

You can get more info on the FOR command by using 'FOR /?' in command prompt. 
/L happened to be the one that worked for me because it builds a set of numbers given start, stop and step values.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted but it worked perfectly for me... `for /L %i in (32000,1,32099) do netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:%i/ user="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"`